# Can't upgrade R because of dependency

Tags: r, linux, upgrade, sudo, apt

I want to upgrade R (version 3.0.2) to a newer version like 3.4.1 but I face a complicated problem in dependency which prevent me to do this.

I typed on terminal many codes using several solutions but I didn't succeed, You can see below my attempts to upgrade it and the warning messages:

```
    sudo apt-get install r-base
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.4.1-2xenial0) but 3.0.2-1ubuntu1   is to be installed
    Depends: r-recommended (= 3.4.1-2xenial0) but 3.0.2-1ubuntu1 is to  be installed
```

I followed all steps on this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-16-04-2) but it didn't work and the result was:

```
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
 sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'
 sudo apt-get update
```

after last code I received the following message:

```
 W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

After that I followed the step on this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347190/dependency-problem-prevent-upgrade?rq=1) and this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283244/apt-get-upgrade-failing-due-to-dependency-issue?rq=1):
when I run  sudo apt-get -f install I get

```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
```

and when I run sudo apt-get upgrade I get:

```
  262 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
  Need to get 4,171 kB/710 MB of archives.

  Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty- updates/main udev amd64 204-5ubuntu20.20
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]
  Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libudev1 amd64 204-5ubuntu20.20
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]
  Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-  updates/main libpam-systemd amd64 204-5ubuntu20.20
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]
  Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main systemd-services amd64 204-5ubuntu20.20
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]
  Err http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_14.10/  owncloud-client-l10n 2.2.4-10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]
  Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libsystemd-daemon0 amd64 204-5ubuntu20.20
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]
  Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libsystemd-login0 amd64 204-5ubuntu20.20
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]
  Err http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_14.10/  owncloud-client 2.2.4-10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]
  Err http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_14.10/  libowncloudsync0 2.2.4-10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]
  Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libgudev-1.0-0 amd64 1:204-5ubuntu20.20
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]
  Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main  libsystemd-journal0 amd64 204-5ubuntu20.20
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]
  Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main isc-dhcp-client amd64 4.2.4-7ubuntu12.8
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]
  Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-  updates/main isc-dhcp-common amd64 4.2.4-7ubuntu12.8
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]
  Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main initramfs-tools all 0.103ubuntu4.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]
  Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main initramfs-tools-bin amd64 0.103ubuntu4.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]
  Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main gir1.2-gudev-1.0 amd64 1:204-5ubuntu20.20
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]
  E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/udev_204-5ubuntu20.20_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]

  E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev1_204-5ubuntu20.20_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]

  E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libpam-systemd_204-5ubuntu20.20_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]

  E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd-services_204-5ubuntu20.20_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]

   E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libsystemd-daemon0_204-5ubuntu20.20_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]

  E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libsystemd-login0_204-5ubuntu20.20_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]

  E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libgudev-1.0-0_204-5ubuntu20.20_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]

 E: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_14.10/./all/owncloud-client-l10n_2.2.4-10.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]

 E: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_14.10/./amd64/owncloud-client_2.2.4-10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]

 E: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_14.10/./amd64/libowncloudsync0_2.2.4-10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]

 E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libsystemd-journal0_204-5ubuntu20.20_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]

 E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/isc-dhcp/isc-dhcp-client_4.2.4-7ubuntu12.8_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]

 E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/isc-dhcp/isc-dhcp-common_4.2.4-7ubuntu12.8_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]

 E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/initramfs-tools/initramfs-tools_0.103ubuntu4.5_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]

 E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/initramfs-tools/initramfs-tools-bin_0.103ubuntu4.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]

 E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/gir1.2-gudev-1.0_204-5ubuntu20.20_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]

 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?


  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 279 not upgraded
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated

Many thanks in advance

P.S: Sorry for my poor skills in Linux but I am trying !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

increase the command to include the packages which `apt` signals as conflicting:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-core
```

You *probably* have to add a few more here.  This is chiefly due to you doing a partial upgrade with an added repo, here from CRAN.

But many of us use these CRAN add-ons and this should work (though I prefer more recent Ubuntu versions but that is a different story).

Comment: AsI said, you may need to _add_ other packages as you progress.  That has fixed the issue for me in the past.

Comment: How this could be possible?

Comment: Crikey, you said it yourself:  _poor skills in Linux_.  Maybe just trust an experienced user, try it and learn?